# PHP/IIS relative includes confusion

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2005, iis-6

I would like to know if this kind of setup is possible as I'm having a lot of trouble setting it up. I am trying to set up a website with a file structure like this:

- **project1** (folder)

  - index.php
  - style.css
  - include.php

    - **admin** (folder)

      - index.php

The parent "project1" folder is located on 'server1' in D:\Projects\project1.

The website is accessed via virtual directory "http://server1/project1".

I would like to be able to write all paths for includes, images srcs, stylesheets etc, in the format '/style.css' so that the files can be found regardless of where they are required. E.g. the following link should work whether it's placed in the 'project1' folder or the 'admin' folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

**EDIT:** as [mellamokb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb) suggested, using href="/project1/style.css" seems to work from both 'index.php' files. However I can't seem to find a similar solution for the PHP INCLUDE.

If I use this...

```
<?php include_once '/include.php'; ?>
```

...in both index.php files, the one in the *admin* directory cannot find the file.

I expected **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** to return "D:\Projects\project1" but it returns D:\staging and I can't work out why. I've tried a few different methods of setting the project 'root' but I've just ended up confusing myself even more! The virtual root of the project should be 'http://server1/project1' and the physical root should be D:\Projects\project1, but I can't work out how to force this.

Comment: What is the virtual directory path to `admin`?  The root-relative path `/style.css` should work if admin is a virtual subdirectory of `http://server/`.

Comment: 'admin' is just a subfolder - do I need to set this up as a separate virtual dir?

Comment: If you navigate to `http://server1/project1/admin/index.php`, a reference to `/style.css` will be resolved by the browser to `http://server1/style.css`, which appears to be correct.  Did you try this and have a problem?

Comment: Yes, if I navigate to `http://server1/project1/admin/index.php`, firefox returns the error

--
`GET http://server1/style.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]`

The error is correct as 'style.css' is located in `http://server1/project1`, not `http://server1/`

Comment: Oh. Then use `/project1/style.css`, or put the resource files in a common virtual folder, like `/resources/style.css`.

Comment: I think I'm confusing matters a bit here; this works perfectly for stylesheets and http links, but if I'm not mistaken the PHP INCLUDE function uses local paths? So using `<?php include '/include.php'; ?>` works from `http://server1/project1/index.php` but not from `'http://server1/project1/admin/index.php'`

Comment: that will surely not work. They are not in the same directory. Read about navigating through directories. check http://forums.htmlhelp.com/index.php?showtopic=2922

Comment: please see: http://php.net/language.constants.predefined - you can include relative to any file with the `__DIR__` constant. That is independent to the webserver or operating system.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a file that contains constants and have something thus `define('BASE_URL', "http://server1/project1/")`. Then you can work relatively using the constant variable `BASE_URL` thus,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>style.css">
```

You can also handle other files by attaching the 'relative' address.

```
include (BASE_URL . '<file you want to add>');
```

Comment: This works well, however I think I'm asking the wrong questions. Your method solves my issue when linking stylesheets etc, but when I try to include a file via PHP INCLUDE, I am struggling to find a universal way of making sure it can find the file

Comment: In addition I have the same problem with stylesheets, e.g. background: url('/Images/background.png') cannot benefit from the constant method :(

Comment: ok... I see the problem. Do structure your folders such that related resources are close to each other. If 'Images' folder is in the same directory as style.css, just do background: url('Images/background.png')